# Android Firebase StorageException Could not get object

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to retrieve an image from firebase to my android app but I'm getting the following error

> E/StorageException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object"  }}
>                                                                     java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object"  }}

The following is the code used to retrieve the file:

```
                storageRef.child("motels/" + mFirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getRef(position).getKey() + "/img_0.jpeg").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
```

The following is the schema of my Firebase reference:[image]

The mFirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getRef(position) returns the correct key, I have checked this by logging it in the console. I have also tried changing the image extension to .jpeg and .jpg

Comment: the location is wrong, did u create a motels folder there?

Comment: Yes, the motels folder is there as you can see on the sceenshot above

Comment: what is `storageRef` equal to?

Comment: storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
  storageRef = storage.getReference();

Answer (score 0):

This error appears when the location is wrong, please change this:

```
 storageRef.child("motels/" + mFirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getRef(position).getKey() + "/img_0.jpeg").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
```

to this:

```
 storageRef.child("motels/img_0.jpeg").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
```

check this for more info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/create-reference

Comment: This is not correct, the image is not in that location, the location looks like this: gs://<myproject>/motels/-KzKr8vtvW-QBuRyAasA/img_0.jpeg
-KzKr8vtvW-QBuRyAasA -> This is the key

Comment: well as said in the answer, that exception appears if you are referencing a wrong location..so double check the location something is missing or you would not have gotten that error